# How to set up Gitlab to post data to an authenticated service?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, githooks

I'm hosting a gitlab. For some of the repos (maybe from different users), I would like to create a tarball for the code and post to a REST API of another service A on each git push.

However, my service A's api requires authentication for access. So I'm using A as an OAuth server to log into gitlab.

Now my question is, how to upload the file properly.

---

A few approaches I am now considering. But I'm not sure if my understandings are correct.

1. Server side git hook. But it seems hooks are purely executable scripts without token or login session information.
2. Webhook. This might work around service A's authentication (or not?), but fails to create a tarball to upload. And it seems users can only control the URL, but are not able to customize the payload?
3. Plugin. Same issue with (1). Authenticated state is lost.
4. CI/CD. Again, same with (1).